# BigDecimal - MathContext.DECIMAL64 vs MathContext.DECIMAL128

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm dealing with the divisions between monetary values. I'm currently using `MathContext.DECIMAL128` as second parameter of `BigDecimal.divide()`. Should I use `MathContext.DECIMAL128` or `MathContext.DECIMAL64`?

Comment: You should use [`a.divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,int,java.math.RoundingMode))

Comment: If this is about real monetary values relating to real money, then I'm sure it is specified somewhere how you should round the (intermediate) steps in your calculation, since it could have a difference in the actual result and in the money that people are owed, received, etc. Without that information, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Andreas: no, that would not work. As Erwin said, you must follow the specs. Some require 4 or more digits for some operations, and some even more for others. Other specs do require rounding to be done to 2 decimals all the time. So it really depends on the specs. Using something like DECIMALxxx is usually wrong, when we talk about money.

Comment: @Andreas: actually even HALF_EVEN is often wrong. It may be called Banker's Rounding, but actually, banks are not specifically known to use it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That was an abbreviated comment, where it was left to the reader to figure out if `2` and `HALF_EVEN` would be appropriate.  If this is for US only (and it very well could be), then `2` is good. Since `HALF_EVEN` is unusual, though not necessarily wrong, showing that in my *example* should make any reader wonder and research what it means and what the alternatives are, to make their own choice. In short, I wholehearted disagree with your hard "no, that would not work", since it may very well work perfectly, and wasn't intended as final answer (hence "should", not "must").

Comment: @Andreas: You posted only that single piece of code and "You should use". No, not necessarily. One should follow the specs, and I am not even sure if `2` would be fine for the US, as single institutions/companies could have different rules for *intermediate results*. Your comment was simply misleading. Even "abbreviated" comments should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between decimal32,decimal64,and decimal128 is (from https://bloomberg.github.io/comdb2/decimals.html):

decimal32 supports exponents between -95 and +96; significand has 7 digits (i.e. 0.000000-9.999999).

The range of numbers representable by this format is +-0.000000x10−95 to +-9.999999x10+96

decimal64 supports exponents between -383 and +384; significand has 16 digits (i.e. 0.000000000000000-9.999999999999999). The range of numbers is +-0.000000000000000x10−383 to +-9.999999999999999x10+384

decimal128 supports exponents between -6143 and +6144; significand has 34 digits (i.e. 0.000000000000000000000000000000000-9.999999999999999999999999999999999).

The range of numbers is +-0.000000000000000000000000000000000x10−6143 to +-9.999999999999999999999999999999999x10+6144

We can find that the difference is range.

BigDecimal supports a special rounding mode:UNLIMITED,But if we use UNLIMITED,
Infinite loop decimal result will throw a ArithmeticException.

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(3);

    BigDecimal result = bd.divide(bd2, MathContext.DECIMAL32);
    System.out.println(result);
    result = bd.divide(bd2, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
    System.out.println(result);
    result = bd.divide(bd2, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    System.out.println(result);
    result = bd.divide(bd2, MathContext.UNLIMITED);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
0.3333333
0.3333333333333333
0.3333333333333333333333333333333333
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

So,if you want larger range of result,you should use decimal128 or UNLIMITED(but be aware of Infinite loop decimal,it will throw ArithmeticException),otherwise,you should use decimal64 or decimal32,Beacuse larger range means worse performance.

Comment: When dealing with monetary arithmetic, using DECIMALxxx is rarely is correct choice.  It is usually preferable to round to specific decimal places instead

Comment: You are right,i missed the key 'monetary',thanks for your correction. :)